# File location(LBA) with concurrent sync write on Ext4, Ext4

Tags: io, filesystems, kernel, ext4, ext3

I experimented for checking the LBA of files using **IOzone**.
I run IOzone with flag -o (sync write) and -i 0 (seq. write) -t 4 (4 thread) -r 32k(32 kilobytes record size).

And I thought that the LBA of 4 files might be split by 32 kilobytes record size and interfere each other. But the result is weird. The files are located with bigger size than I expected. And the size is 2x bigger each chucks. Actually i tried that on ext4 before. And I thought the reason is the multi block allocator of ext4. But it's same on ext3. After that, I checked the request size using blktrace. And the request size was 32KB as I expected.

I can't figure out the reason. I post it with the result of my experiment

Please help me guys.

Thank you for reading my question.

[image]

Comment: Ext4 adopts multiblock allcoation and pre-allocation.